# How do I give the Gift of Ubuntu One music store

Tags: ubuntu-one

I would like to give my adult child  a paid ubuntu one account as a gift. How do I pay for his account, and make it surprise? Gift certificate? Prepaid?

Answer (score 2):

We don't currently have a way to do this, sorry.