# How would people give me a gift from the Ubuntu One music store?

Tags: ubuntu-one, music

I want to stop getting new music on CDs, and transition to a 'downloads only' regime.  I am considering signing up to an Ubuntu One Music Streaming subscription, but I am aware that a lot of the CDs I have obtained in the past were gifts from my family.  How would my family & others give me a music album from the Ubuntu One music store as a gift?  Do they need to have an Ubuntu One account themselves?

Or, if it is not possible to give a specific music album, can they give some kind of credit / voucher / gift certificate?

N.B. This is different from [the question of how to give the Ubuntu One Music Streaming subscription itself as a gift](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88875/how-do-i-give-the-gift-of-ubuntu-one-music-store).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ubuntu One music store does not currently have a gift/voucher system. Others would need to just give you a general pre-filled gift card, from VISA, Mastercard, or similar, that can be accepted by the store as a credit card, or send you money via Paypal.

Comment: Thanks.
Can I suggest (to whom it may concern) that this would make a good addition to the FAQ?  Also, if there is a plan to introduce this feature, could we sign-up to be notified when it becomes available?